# How To Get App To Move To Home Screen If Logged In? (Flutter, Firebase)

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to get my app to verify whether the user is logged in, in order to have the home screen seen instead of the login screen. How do I do so?

Below is the root screen to check if the user is logged in

` class Root extends StatefulWidget {
Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
      @override
      State<Root> createState() => _RootState();
    }
    
      class _RootState extends State<Root> {
      AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.notLoggedIn;
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
       
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        switch(_authStatus){
          case AuthStatus.notLoggedIn:
          return AuthScreen();
          break;
          case AuthStatus.loggedIn:
          return HomePage();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    
    enum AuthStatus{
      loggedIn,
      notLoggedIn
    }
 
class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier{
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  
  Future<User?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    var user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return user.user;
  }

 
  signOut() async {
    return await _auth.signOut();
  }

  
  Future<User?> createPerson(String name, String email, String password) async {
    var user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    

    return user. user;
  }
}

  Future<String> currentUser() async{
  User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  return user.uid;
}

  void _toNextPage(BuildContext context){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => SignUp())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I dont know the firebase coding.but I write the code how you handle the condation  and remove the switch condation

```
@override
      void initState() {
   
        Timer(
            Duration(seconds: 5),
            () {
              if(AuthStatus.loggedIn){
                Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                        (route) => false);
                        
              }else if(AuthStatus.notLoggedIn){
                Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                        (route) => false);
              }
            });
        super.initState();
      }
```